# What was up with the lights in the sky tonight?

Tags: light

I and my boyfriend where looking up in the sky tonight around 8:30 am. We noticed about 17 or more things, that looked like stars. They was perfectly spaced, and just vanished they was heading east. It lasted about 5 to 10 minutes. What could it be?

Comment: Can you mention your latitude? If they were artificial satellites (e.g. Starlink) they would be hard to see if the Sun was up, which in many places it is at '830 am'. Thanks!

Comment: Please share rough coordinates, so that one has a chance to look up what it might have been